# How to make dynamic tooltip in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to view my dynamic content in my tooltip Please check my code

**js**

```
function workTitle($worktype) {
    var $title = '';
    if ($worktype === 1) {
        $title = "Print Ready File";
    } else if ($worktype === 2) {
        $title = "Design Work";
    } else if ($worktype === 3) {
        $title = "Design Only";
    } else if ($worktype === 4) {
        $title = "Website";
    }
    return $title;
}

function workType($worktype) {
    var $ass = '';
    if ($worktype == 1) {
        $ass = "p";
    } else if ($worktype == 2) {
        $ass = "d";
    } else if ($worktype == 3) {
        $ass = "do";
    } else if ($worktype == 4) {
        $ass = "w";
    }
    return $ass;
}
```

**controller**

```
$scope.work_type = function(work_type) {
    return $scope.ship= workType(work_type);
};
$scope.work_title = function(wtype) {
    return $scope.title= workTitle(wtype);
};
```

**views**

```
<span class="badge"
   uib-tooltip="{{work_title(order.Order.work_type) | uppercase}}"
   ng-bind-html="work_type(order.Order.work_type) | uppercase"></span>
```

Above my HTML code `ng-bind-html` working fine. But I want to show full text in my `uib-tooltip` attribute. Please help me.

Comment: remove | uppercase from tootip ...and instead case in thr function work_title to (workTitle(wtype)).toUpperCase()

Comment: Actually the tooltip is coming. But as the name is very small, it is getting displayed on on center and you r not able to see properly. Need to modify it.

Comment: I got it there was problem in conditonal Identity `===` I have replaced with `==` now working fine.